# Stacks in moduli spaces of sheaves research

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I want to get some practice and build more appreciation for the use of stacks in the context of classical moduli spaces of sheaves. Here by classical I vaguely mean hands-on description of the geometry of moduli spaces of sheaves in the spirit of work of Drézet-Le Potier and the book of Huybrechts-Lehn. Two great papers I've read so far which use stacky techniques are Walter's "Irreducibility of moduli spaces of vector bundles on birationally ruled surfaces" and Göttsche-Hirschowitz's "Weak Brill-Noether for vector bundles on the projective plane".

Can you recommend me more great papers using stacks to prove things about moduli spaces of sheaves?

Comment: My advisor Izzet Coskun has, with various collaborators, published extensively about moduli spaces of sheaves, mostly on various rational surfaces, in the last 7 years or so. I would look at the papers on his website. I can't really wrap my head around this stuff, but I know that the stack of prioritary sheaves often comes up in the proofs.

Comment: @TabesBridges, thank you for your comment. I am very familiar with Izzet's techniques and as far as I know he and his collaborators mostly build on geometric properties of that stack proved by Walter in the paper I mentioned above.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the info.